# airplay on an iPad app

Tags: ipad, ios4, airplay

is it possible to enable Airplay on an iPad app I've made that streams audio (no video). If so, is there any sample code out there?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO

The RAOP protocol is private and the stream is encrypted.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Audio_Output_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

This may be of interest:

[AirPlay Overview: Encryption and Authentication](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EncryptionandAuthentication/EncryptionandAuthentication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045-CH5-SW1)

This part indicates that it may be possible to play what is streaming over AirPlay:

> Bear in mind that if the video is playing over AirPlay, the viewer is watching on a television with no way to enter a password. In such cases, the viewer must authenticate on the device that is relaying the video via AirPlay, which may be in another room. This situation has other implications, including how long cookies or other authentication tokens should last before expiration. You should configure your server accordingly.